Why do the QGraphicsBlurEffect makes my QGraphicsView not work?
I am using the QGraphicsView widget on PyQt5 and I created some custom QGraphicsItems.
When I instantiate without any effect my items, I get this :

When I add those three lines :
        blur = _QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()
        blur.setBlurRadius(1.1)
        self.setGraphicsEffect(blur)

in the "grand-parent" of my custom items, I get this :

Moreover, nothing seems to move, my mouse don't move, the deck don't do anything...
I found this post but it didn't help me, every hint I passed as an argument made the same result.
I also tried to directly pass the blur effect on the QGraphicsView, but it only works when the QGraphicsView changes (resize, ...) and is not applied with any update of the items.
What should I do?
Thanks for you help!
EDIT :
After having set correctly the bounding rects of each element, I got this :

But I still have the problem that the animations don't work, the mouse don't move, and others...
To reproduce
Here is a little way to reproduce it, containing only the background and the mouse :
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as _QtWidgets, uic as _uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore as _QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui as _QtGui

class GameWidget(_QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self._scene: _QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene = _QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        
        self._main_graphic = MainDisplayedElement()
        self._main_graphic.setZValue(-10)
        self._scene.addItem(self._main_graphic)
        
        self._mouse = MouseDisplayedElement()
        self._mouse.set_size(40)
        
        self._mouse.setZValue(1000)
        
        self._scene.addItem(self._mouse)
        
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.setInteractive(True)
        
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(_QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(_QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        
    def onShow(self):
        self.resizeEvent()
    
    def resizeEvent(self, event = None) -> None:
        w, h = self.width() - 2, self.height() - 2
        
        self.setSceneRect(-w / 2, -h / 2, w, h)
        self._main_graphic.set_rect(-w / 2, -h / 2, w, h)
    
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event: _QtGui.QMouseEvent) -> None:
        super().mouseMoveEvent(event)
        
        position: _QtCore.QPointF = event.pos()
        
        position.setX(int(position.x() - self.width() / 2))
        position.setY(int(position.y() - self.height() / 2))
        
        event.ignore()
        
        x, y = position.x(), position.y()
        self._mouse.set_position(x, y)
        
        self._scene.update()

class GameDisplayedElement(_QtWidgets.QGraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, width: int, height: int, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self._width: int = width
        self._height: int = height
        self._x: int = x
        self._y: int = y
        
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setAcceptedMouseButtons(_QtCore.Qt.MouseButton.AllButtons)
        
        # Here are the three lines...
        blur = _QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()
        blur.setBlurRadius(1.1)
        blur.setBlurHints(_QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect.BlurHint.QualityHint)
        self.setGraphicsEffect(blur)
        
    def paint(self, painter: _QtGui.QPainter, options: _QtWidgets.QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget: _QtWidgets.QWidget) -> None:
        pass
    
    def boundingRect(self) -> _QtCore.QRectF:
        x = self._x - self._width / 2
        y = self._y - self._height / 2
        
        return _QtCore.QRectF(int(x), int(y), int(self._width), int(self._height))

class MainDisplayedElement(GameDisplayedElement):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        self._size = 150
        
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(False)
        self.setAcceptedMouseButtons(_QtCore.Qt.MouseButton.NoButton)
    
    def paint(self, painter: _QtGui.QPainter, options: _QtWidgets.QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget: _QtWidgets.QWidget) -> None:
        a = open("./any_image.png", "rb")
        data = a.read()
        a.close()
        
        image = _QtGui.QImage.fromData(data) # use any QImage you want
    
        x = 0
        while x - self._size <= self._width / 2:
            y = 0
            while y - self._size <= self._height / 2:
                painter.drawImage(_QtCore.QRectF(x, y, self._size, self._size), image)
                painter.drawImage(_QtCore.QRectF(-x-self._size, y, self._size, self._size), image)
                painter.drawImage(_QtCore.QRectF(x, -y-self._size, self._size, self._size), image)
                painter.drawImage(_QtCore.QRectF(-x-self._size, -y-self._size, self._size, self._size), image)
                y += self._size
            x += self._size
    
    def set_rect(self, x: float, y: float, w: float, h: float) -> None:
        self._x = 0
        self._y = 0
        self._width = w
        self._height = h
    
class MouseDisplayedElement(GameDisplayedElement):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(0, 0, 50, 50, parent)
        
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(False)
        self.setAcceptedMouseButtons(_QtCore.Qt.MouseButton.NoButton)
    
    def paint(self, painter: _QtGui.QPainter, options: _QtWidgets.QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget: _QtWidgets.QWidget) -> None:
        a = open("./any_image.png", "rb")
        data = a.read()
        a.close()
        
        image = _QtGui.QImage.fromData(data) # use any QImage you want
    
        painter.drawImage(_QtCore.QRectF(self._x, self._y, self._width, self._height), image)
    
    def set_size(self, size: int) -> None:
        self._width, self._height = size, size
    
    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event: _QtGui.QHoverEvent) -> None:
        event.ignore()
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        event.ignore()
        
    def set_position(self, x: int, y: int) -> None:
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
    
app = _QtWidgets.QApplication([''])

widg = GameWidget()
widg.show()

app.exec()
    

Change the path of the item in the paint method of both items to test it. You'll see the mouse don't move with the three lines, and move without them, as the background dosn't resize with the tree lines and resize succesfully without them.
Context
About my environment, I am using Python3.10.12, with PyQt5 and qt5.15.3 (given with the qtdiag command) ; I am using an x86-64 computer with Ubuntu22.04 LTS.

Please provide a [mre] and also include relevant environment info, such as OS, PyQt and Qt version.

My project is publicly available on https://www.github.com/KakiIn/LoveLetterClient ; the QGraphicsView is in the "views/game.py" file and the QGraphicsItems are in the "graphics" folder.

using the command qtdiag showed me the 5.15.3 version of qt, but I am not sure.

You will find the three lines in the "element.py" file, that I have pushed rn

No, sorry. Questions must be self contained, and cannot rely on external resources (especially repositories). Please take your time and provide an adequate MRE.

Ok sorry. I edit now so.

I did it, but I am afraid that the code is too long... anyway, I tested it and it still makes error only when the three lines are present.

The main issue with the effect is the radius is too small. Unless you apply a scale transformation that "zooms" in, its result is negligible, as it's smaller than one pixel. You have more important issues, though: 1. the boundingRect() is not properly updated with prepareGeometryChange() before changing with set_rect() (or set_size()) as the docs clearly point out; 2. the position is not properly set, as you should use setPos(), not updating the internal _x, and _y values, unless you call prepareGeometryChange as written above. Without those, no proper update will happen.

Note that there are also other issues in your implementation. Among others, continuously opening the image file within paint() is extremely inefficient: you should open the image somewhere else (possibly, in the __init__) and keep a persistent reference to it, so that it can be directly used when painting is required. Also, if you want a "background texture" for the whole scene, there's no point in using a graphics item: in fact, you can just use QGraphicsScene.setBackgroundBrush() with a QBrush created on a QPixmap.

It is what I do, I just replaced it for the exmaplw but all the images are defined outside the graphic items. For the brush, I find it better with the item, because I can set the size, the central point, etc...

But still thanks for all your advice, I really appreciate it

@musicamante You were right, I needed to add the prepareGeometryChange call. Could you make an answer for me to mark this issue as resolved? Thanks for all!

According to @musicamante (thanks to you), the only thing I was missing is the call for the prepareGeometryChange method in my resizing and deplacing functions :
    def set_size(self, size: int) -> None:
        self._width, self._height = size, size
        self.prepareGeometryChange() # this will make the graphics item update again


And a possibility is also to only apply the blurred effect to the images when I paint them (it was better in my case), found in this answer :
    def applyEffectToImage(self, src: _QtGui.QImage, effect: _QtWidgets.QGraphicsEffect, extent: int = 0) -> _QtGui.QImage:
        scene = _QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        item = _QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        item.setPixmap(_QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(src))
        item.setGraphicsEffect(effect)
        scene.addItem(item)
        res = _QtGui.QImage(src.size() + _QtCore.QSize(extent*2, extent*2), _QtGui.QImage.Format.Format_ARGB32)
        res.fill(_QtCore.Qt.GlobalColor.transparent)
        ptr = _QtGui.QPainter(res)
        scene.render(ptr, _QtCore.QRectF(), _QtCore.QRectF( -extent, -extent, src.width()+extent*2, src.height()+extent*2 ) )
        ptr.end()
        return res

Like that, I can draw all my graphics and only apply the blur to the images that need it.
EDIT : Some corrections

Instead of using my own position system, it is better to use the position system of Qt:

    def set_position(self, x: int, y: int) -> None:
        self.setX(x)
        self.setY(y)

    def boundingRect(self) -> _QtCore.QRectF: 
        x = -self._width / 2 # centered element; otherwise 0
        y = -self._height / 2 # centered element; otherwise 0
        
        return _QtCore.QRectF(int(x), int(y), int(self._width), int(self._height))

Like that, I don't need to use prepareGeometryChange, neither to use the xy coordinates inside the paint and boundingRect functions (better)

I shouldn't load my images each time I draw them (I should load theme one time first)

In __init__():
        a = open("./any_image.png", "rb")
        data = a.read()
        a.close()
        
        blur = _QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect()
        blur.setBlurRadius(1.1)
        blur.setBlurHints(_QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect.BlurHint.QualityHint)
        self._image = self.applyEffectToImage(_QtGui.QImage.fromData(data), blur) # use any QImage you want

In paint(), for the mouse:
    painter.drawImage(_QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, self._size, self._size), self._image) # not x and y because of the first reason

Like that, I can use a blur directly on the image, without reloading it everytime.
I would like to thank @musicamante again for all of his advice.

Note: prepareGeometryChange() does not just make the item update again: it actually ensures that an item is redrawn when necessary. The Graphics View framework uses various optimization strategies in order to be able to show scenes with thousands of complex elements, and one of them is caching whatever is being painted the first time and only update the bounding rect of each item if it finds it required. Failing to call that function when the bounding rect theoretically changes means that the scene will never know that: 1. a new rect has to be repainted; 2. the area previously covered by »

» the original rect also need repainting (because the item does not exist there anymore). This is extremely important also to avoid painting artifacts ("ghosts"), and the boundingRect() documentation explains it clearly: "all painting must be restricted to inside an item's bounding rect. [...] otherwise, the scene will be unaware of the item's new geometry, and the results are undefined (typically, rendering artifacts are left within the view)". Note that, while your approach of rendering a "dummy" item may work for simple usage, »

» may also be inaccurate, especially if transformations (scaling, rotation, etc) are applied to the scene or the item itself, causing a "rasterized" effect that may not be desirable and that could also cause other types of artifacts, such as further aliasing or oddly pixelated images. Graphics View processing is normally quite fast, and if you're using standard graphics items (such as QGraphicsPixmapItem, without overriding paint(), or by implementing it carefully), the performance will still be good, while avoiding possible drawing issues.

Don't hesitate to edit, because I guess you know better than me how it should be... after having use the coordinates of qt instead of _x and _y, it works better.

I'd prefer not to, it's not my habit to make such important changes to posts. My suggestion is to do it on your own: creating/expanding your own answers by clarifying what you do and why is an extremely helpful learning tool. You don't have to do it right now, as the current answer may suffice and the official docs are fine enough; there's always time to review your own posts (and get more experienced in the meantime): I remember editing and improving answers I wrote years before. Just remember that the Graphics View framework is as powerful as it is complex: be patient with your learning.

Alright, I'll do so. Thanks again!
